# tagging content with geolocation

Tags: web, geolocation

I am trying to develop an application where users will post content.  It is a user-generated application, so every post will have a location attached to it, so that it can be filtered later for other users in that area or city.

For example: say users can list books on my website to sell.  Now while listing I want to provide them a text box where they can enter a location.  Now the entered location should be valid, so how do I verify that?

Also after posting the book, someone else searches for a book in his location then he/she should not only get results for his location but other nearby locations too.

These are few of my questions.  If someone can answer them and guide me, I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To verify people's location, you'll want to use the HTML5 geolocation capabilities.  Take a look here for a demo:  http://merged.ca/iphone/html5-geolocation

Searching nearby is a bit trickier, but there are a few options.  You could use a geocoding service (Google and Bing for example both offer geocoding REST APIs) to determine if people are in the same city, zip code, etc.  Perhaps a better solution is to use database queries to search for nearby posts.  Many databases now offer built-in geospatial data types to support exactly this kind of scenario.  MySQL for example:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-spatial-datatypes.html